# which http://search.twitter.com/search.json should I use to get response from Twitter?

Tags: javascript, ajax, twitter

The problem I'm facing is that I cat not manage the request to the twitter-search. I think because the twitter url is not working anymore. If i type the url in my browser, I'm getting this error "{"errors":[{"message":"The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active. Please migrate to API v1.1. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview.","code":64}]}".

I have already tried to fix it by replace the url with "url: 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json'" but it was not helpful.

No error is being displayed on the console.

I appreciate any help.

```js
<html>
<head>

 <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
 <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">

<title>Demo</title>
</head>

<body>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>

<script>
 
    $.searchTwitter = function(search){
     $.ajax({
      //url: 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json',
      url: 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json',
      data: { q:search},
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      success: function(results){
       console.log(results);
      }
     });

     $.searchTwitter('dog');
    }

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Goggle brings me many answers

Comment: i have already goggled and found the url in the code

Comment: But that's clearly explained as i can see it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the same page that you told

I quote

> Please note that now API v1.1 requires that the request must be authenticated, check Authentication & Authorization documentation for more details on how to do it. Also note that the search results at twitter.com may return historical results while the Search API usually only serves tweets from the past week.

check this page
https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/application-only

best